# Using jenkins parameters in same build configuration

Tags: jenkins

I want to use a parameterized build, which use this parameters in the configuration itself.

[image: definition of parameterized build]

so a few steps later, I want to use the parameter to start the jenkins job in the parameter var "jenkins-deployment"

[image: how to use the $param in this field?]

Is there a way in jenkins to use the "jenkins-deployment" var in this scope?

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve that using the [Build Flow plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Flow+Plugin).

In my example, I created a job A to trigger another job called "Test on console log".

Job A parameter:

[image]

Job A build flow step:

[image]

Console output:

[image]

Another solution is to use the [Workflow plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-plugin/blob/master/README.md#introduction) as described [here](https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-plugin/blob/master/TUTORIAL.md#using-slaves).

Comment: Thats a nice "workaround" which works well for its own. Unfortunately it doesn't work with my existing Jenkins system here, because it prevents to connect some slaves to the system. So its not working for me. :(

Comment: Another option is to use the Workflow plugin as described here: https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-plugin/blob/master/TUTORIAL.md#using-slaves (I've updated my answer)

Comment: Is there really no other way to do this? Some kind of variable substitution that can be used directly in the project configuration?

Comment: With Jenkins 2.0 and the pipeline jobs, maybe there are some new solutions. My environment is always on Jenkins 1.6, I have to upgrade to do some tests.